# Resources for developing prognostic index-scores

Tags: modeling, logistic, references, validation

I am looking for online resources or books explaining how to develop prognostic indexes-scores step by step. I am mainly wondering about model validation and transformation of regression coefficients into scoring systems.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be good places to start.

- *Clinical Prediction Models: A Practical Approach to Development, Validation, and Updating* by Dr. E.W. Steyerberg
- *Regression Modeling Strategies: With Applications to Linear Models, Logistic Regression, and Survival Analysis* by our moderator, Dr. Frank E. Harrell

I particularly like case studies. Dr. Harrell's book has one on "Predicting Cause of Death" and "Survival of Titanic Passengers". Dr. Steyerberg's book has a number of helpful case studies as well.